# Unity 3D character prefab not rotating as a whole

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am learning Unity, 3d free look camera and no errors, the only problem is the face and hands of the character doesn't rotate, only the armor of the character is rotating when I go to a different direction. I am using a free viking prefab from unity asset store as game character, the prefab has two child the face&hands and the armor. On the line "child = transform.GetChild(0).transform;" when I replace the 0 with 1 only the face and hands rotate. How can I make the whole prefab rotate when moving around?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
private Player playerInput;
private CharacterController controller;
private Vector3 playerVelocity;
private bool groundedPlayer;

[SerializeField]
private float playerSpeed = 2.0f;
[SerializeField]
private float jumpHeight = 1.0f;
[SerializeField]
private float gravityValue = -9.81f;
[SerializeField]
private float rotationSpeed = 4f;

private Transform cameraMain;
private Transform child;

private void Awake()
{
    playerInput= new Player();
    controller= GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

private void OnEnable()
{
    playerInput.Enable();
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    playerInput.Disable();
}

private void Start()
{
    cameraMain = Camera.main.transform;
    child = transform.GetChild(0).transform;

}

void Update()
{
    groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;
    if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0)
    {
        playerVelocity.y = 0f;
    }

    Vector2 movementInput= playerInput.PlayerMain.Move.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    Vector3 move = (cameraMain.forward * movementInput.y + cameraMain.right * 
movementInput.x);
    move.y = 0f;
    controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

    // Changes the height position of the player..
    if (playerInput.PlayerMain.Jump.triggered && groundedPlayer)
    {
        playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);
    }

    playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);

    if (movementInput != Vector2.zero)
    {
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(child.localEulerAngles.x, 
cameraMain.localEulerAngles.y, child.localEulerAngles.z));
        child.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(child.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * 
rotationSpeed);
    }
}

}
```